# How to calculate variance between observations, when observations are in matrix form each

Tags: r, matrix, variance

I have a cluster of 250 observations. each observation is a 4 by 9 matrix.
4 is number of variable parameters observed and 9 is number of days, observations were collected.

I want to know the variance between 250 observations which are in matrix form. as I ve studied so far, variance is calculated among one dimension variables.
any suggestion for data in matrix form?

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(0:69),10,7)
mat2 <- matrix(c(3:72),10,7)
mat3 <- matrix(c(0:69),10,7)
...
var <- var(mat1,mat2, mat3,..)
```

for these three matrices, var() returns a 7 by 7 matrix of 9.166667 for all elements. I do not know what r is doing. or how to get to this.

Comment: *"each observation is a 4 by 9 matrix"* does not match `matrix(.,10,7)`, please clarify.

Comment: When posting questions like this, when you get warnings you do not understand, you really should not ignore them. In this case, `Warning in if (na.rm) "na.or.complete" else "everything" : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` is a good hint. `var` accepts *one or two data arguments*; the call is being interpreted as `var(x=mat1, y=mat2, na.rm=mat3)`, which will fail.

Comment: Once you clarify the dimension question, please explain what you expect the output to be. If you can, please be specific and accurate, giving the intended variance for at least one of the dimensions/cells you're examining. (For the sake of simplicity, I recommend sticking with just the 3-5 matrices; your reproducible question has a good start, we just need reproducible results.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to var are:

```
> args(var)
function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use)
```

so mat1 is being passed to x and mat2 to y and mat3 to na.rm.  Element i, j of the result is the covariance of x[, i] and y[, j].

The code in the question really all makes no sense and some reading of ?var would help.  It is not clear what "I want to know the variance between 250 observations which are in matrix form" means.  If it means that v[i, j] should be calculated as the variance of c(mat1[i,j], mat2[i, j], mat3[i, j]) then we can use one of several list comprehension packages or just iterated sapply.  They all use the fact that these two are the same for fixed i and j except the first is more general.

```
var(sapply(L, `[`, i, j)) 
var(c(L[[1]][i, j], L[[2]][i,j], L[[3]][i,j]))
```

The syntax for the listcompr alternative seems particularly intuitive here.

```
L <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)
nr <- nrow(L[[1]])
nc <- ncol(L[[1]])  

library(listcompr)
v1 <- gen.matrix(var(sapply(L, `[`, i, j)), i = 1:nr, j = 1:nc)

# or
library(eList)
v2 <- Mat(for(j in 1:nc) for(i in 1:nr) var(sapply(L, `[`, i, j)))

# or (no packages):
v3 <- sapply(1:nc, \(j) sapply(1:nr, \(i) var(sapply(L, `[`, i, j))))

# checks

identical(v1, v2)
## [1] TRUE

identical(v1, v3)
## [1] TRUE

i <- 2; j <- 3
identical(v1[i, j], var(c(L[[1]][i, j], L[[2]][i,j], L[[3]][i,j])))
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will reflect what you're hoping for.

First, I'll create a few matrices, very small:

```r
set.seed(42)
mat1 <- matrix(sample(100,12),2,4)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(100,12),2,4)
mat3 <- matrix(sample(100,12),2,4)
```

From here, I think you want to get

```r
var(c(mat1[1,1], mat2[1,1], mat3[1,1]))
# [1] 193
```

but for every set of cells in all matrices.

One way to do this is to `abind` all matrices into a 3D array and then use `apply`:

```r
ary <- do.call(abind::abind, c(list(mat1, mat2, mat3), along = 3))
ary
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   49   25   18   47
# [2,]   65   74  100   24
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   26   41   27    5
# [2,]    3   89   36   84
# , , 3
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   24   43   22    8
# [2,]   30   15   58   36

apply(ary, 1:2, var)
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3] [,4]
# [1,] 193.0000   97.33333   20.33333  549
# [2,] 966.3333 1530.33333 1057.33333 1008
```

Where `193` is the variance of the `[1,1]` elements, `97.333` is the variance of the `[1,2]` elements, etc.